# Set text inside xml layout from JSON file

Tags: android, json, xml, string, android-contentprovider

I'm searching for a way to do this.
I' have a JSON file inside may project, for example mystrings.json, that is like this:

```
{
"ErrorCodes.1": "Hai superato il tempo limite",
"ErrorCodes.2": "Hai superato il tempo limite"
}
```

i want to use this json in this way:

```
<TextView
  android:text="@ErrorCodes.1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

There is a way to accomplish?
I'm searching but without results.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: no you cant do some thing like this parse. You have to parse the json and set the `json` value to the  `textview`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform this with use of [Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)

1. Parse your `JSON` file and set it inside model class(i.e. UserModel, ErrorModel etc).
2. Bind that model class to `xml` file

   ```
   <data>
     <variable name="user" type="com.example.User"/>
   </data>
   ```
3. Set values in `TextView`

   ```
   <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@{user.error}"/>
   ```
4. Perform binding in your `Activity`

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       MainActivityBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.main_activity);
       User user = get your model class here;
       binding.setUser(user);
   }
   ```

Here are some tutorials of `Data Binding`, you can refer those.

[Working with Data Binding Android](http://www.androidgig.com/working-with-databinding-android/) by Ravi Rupareliya
[DataBinding: how to develop Android apps faster](https://stfalcon.com/en/blog/post/faster-android-apps-with-databinding)
[No More findViewById](https://medium.com/google-developers/no-more-findviewbyid-457457644885#.twkyo45ke) by George Mount
[Develop apps faster using Data Binding – Part 1](http://chintanrathod.com/develop_apps_faster_using_data_binding_part1/) by Chintan Rathod